# What standards exist for the naming and abreviation of colleges?

Tags: administration, tools

#### Background:

Currently, I am trying to manually scrape the contents of a transfer map tool hosted on Arizona State University's website. I was pretty successful in deconstructing how the URL for the tool/webpage works, but found a strange naming convention for its colleges.

Specifically, the colleges are named using acronyms that don't align with the names of the schools.

For example, W.P. Carrey is shortened to CBA and Ira A. Fulton is shortened to CES in the URL. As far as I know, ASU doesn't use these acronyms to name their schools.

However, W.P. Carrey is ASU's school/college for business administration, and Ira A. Fulton is ASU's school/college for engineering. To add to that I have seen other Universities use these acronyms to name their colleges.

Here's the whole list of acronyms used by the tool:
[image]

#### Question (TL;DR):

I was wondering if these types of acronyms have a naming standard associated with them? Something for me to reference while scraping the site?

Comment: Do you have examples for other universities? For ASU, they may have their own naming conventions. CBA may stand for College of Business Administration. CES may stand for College of Engineering school, etc. Every university can have their own conventions.

Comment: Indeed, and then someone gave a boatload of money and had the unit named after them…

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I was wondering if these types of acronyms have a naming standard associated with them? Something for me to reference while scraping the site?

I feel confident in saying no, there is no such thing. Even within university systems, names are all over the place, for example "Schools of X" and "Colleges of Y" are sometimes the same level, sometimes not.

Answer (score 1):

> Was wondering if these types of acronyms have a naming standard associated with them? Something for me to reference while scraping the site?

No. To provide an example building upon an answer by [Azor Ahai](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/191375/33210), consider an *EEB* department.

These departments are typically macro-biology (often the old botany and zoology departments merged together). EEB can stand for several titles including

- [Ecology, Evolution and Behavior](https://cbs.umn.edu/academics/departments/eeb),
- [Ecology & Evolutionary Biology](https://eeb.princeton.edu/), and
- [Evolution, Ecology, and Behavior](https://biology.indiana.edu/graduate/evolution-ecology-behavior/faculty/index.html).